# generate list of tuples to import to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

I have found a list of consonant cluster with the following code:

```
list_2 = ['financial','disastrous','accuracy','important','numbers']
reg = r'[bdðfghjklmnprstvxþ]+'
d = []
largest = []
for w in list_2:
    d.append(re.findall(reg, str(w), re.IGNORECASE))
print(d)
```

[['f', 'n', 'n', 'l'], ['d', 's', 'str', 's'], ['r'], ['mp', 'rt', 'nt'], ['n', 'mb', 'rs']]

I need to get the largest consonant count for each word to import as list (of tuples) to a pandas dataframe. I have tried various things but without success.

Comment: The tuple should be (word, int(largest cluster in word))

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the int you are looking for:

```
def largest_cluster(cons_list):
    return max(len(c) for c in cons_list)
```

Then you can get the tuples by:

```
tuples = [(w, largest_cluster(cons)) for w, cons in zip(list2, d)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine, now to import it to pandas with column labels. That will hopefully be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If the word has no consonants I get ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence. How do I fix that?